# Load NSMutableDictionary from plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist, nsmutabledictionary

I'm trying to load an NSMutableDictionary from a Plist. My result is always NULL.

Plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>LocNum</key>
            <string>0</string>
            <key>LocName</key>
            <string>Head</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>LocNum</key>
            <string>1</string>
            <key>LocName</key>
            <string>Left Hand</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>LocNum</key>
            <string>2</string>
            <key>LocName</key>
            <string>Right Hand</string>
        </dict>
       ....
    </array>
</plist>
```

My code is pretty simple:

```
locDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSString *locListpath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"LocList" ofType:@"plist"];
locDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:locListpath];
NSLog(@"locDictionary %@", locDictionary);
```

Any thoughts or help? Thanks

Comment: the filenames are case sensitive, check to see if you have entered the proper file name, also the root is array and not dict

Comment: FYI - the line `locDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];` is pointless. Get rid of that line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your plist is not `NSDictionary`, but `NSArray` of dictionaries, if it is placed in proper place on disk then this code should help:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"LocList" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray *locArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your plist defines an array of dictionaries, not a dictionary itself, so you  need to initiate an array:

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:locListpath];
```

and then loop through the array to get the individual dictionaries with something like:

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {
...
}
```